# Tensorflow keras multiprocessing leaves threads open

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-multiprocessing

I have this problem where I am trying to do deep learning, with dataset that contains about 5 million samples stored in a h5 format. I use generators in fitting (h5imagegenerator), and enable multiprocessing to train faster. The problem is, that Tensorflow Keras seems to like to leave processes hanging and does not clean them up when fitting has ended, so when I do next fitting if using same generators, it just hangs, if I create new generators, it works, but starts spitting out error messages from other threads.

Some code for this context:

```
#Generator creation
def getGenerators():
    print("Create training generator")
    traingen = train_generator = HDF5ImageGenerator(
                                            src='./storage.h5',
                                            X_key='X',
                                            y_key='Y',
                                            num_classes=1,
                                            scaler=False,
                                            labels_encoding=False,
                                            batch_size=512
                                            )
    print("Create validation generator")
    validgen = train_generator = HDF5ImageGenerator(
                                            src='./validate.h5',
                                            X_key='X',
                                            y_key='Y',
                                            num_classes=1,
                                            scaler=False,
                                            labels_encoding=False,
                                            batch_size=512
                                            )
    return (traingen, validgen)
```

I've omitted the normal network building and compilation code, it is known to work. The main program is inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Training loop:

```
#Do fitting rounds and
    for i in range(1,300):
        traingen, validgen = getGenerators() #I need to create new generators for each round so second round doesn't hang
        lr = 0.003*(0.99**i) #Exponential learning rate decay
        print("Round {:}, lr = {:}".format(i,lr))
        backend.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, lr)#Setting LR
        model.fit(
            x=traingen, #I use generators here, everything is "set" to show all values
            y=None,
            batch_size=32,
            epochs=1,
            verbose=2,
            callbacks=None,
            validation_split=0.0,
            validation_data=validgen,
            shuffle=False, #Data generated is in random order, and shuffling takes way too long
            class_weight=None,
            sample_weight=None,
            initial_epoch=0,
            steps_per_epoch=int(len(traingen)), #Number of batches
            validation_steps=1,
            validation_batch_size=32,
            validation_freq=1,
            max_queue_size=60, #Does fit in memory, leaves ~10GB of free ram
            workers=10, #I have 16 cores, but 10 seems to already work well, and increase does not seem to have a benefit
            use_multiprocessing=True #To make it fast
        )
        time.sleep(1) #These sleeps are an attempt to give the running threads time to exit
        model.save(r'./model') #Save model
        time.sleep(1)
        backend.clear_session() #I was hoping this would kill processes, but it just keeps things clean
        traingen = None #If I don't set these to none, the training will hang regardless of new generators on the first line
        validgen = None
        time.sleep(1)
        model = models.load_model(r'./model') #Load to start again
        time.sleep(1)
```

Some errors I've observed:

```
Exception in thread Thread-44:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 744, in _run
    with closing(self.executor_fn(_SHARED_SEQUENCES)) as executor:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 721, in pool_fn
    pool = get_pool_class(True)(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function Model.make_test_function.<locals>.test_function at 0x000001670D2304C0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.


Exception in thread Thread-34:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 744, in _run
    with closing(self.executor_fn(_SHARED_SEQUENCES)) as executor:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 721, in pool_fn
    pool = get_pool_class(True)(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Eventually the thread number seems to go down to what it was supposed to be, but is there a way to clean up old threads so that resources can be freed? This code as it is now does train a network successfully, but now I need to do unsanitary work to make it run, and I'd like to just terminate all unnecessary processes and then start fitting anew.